# Degree of parallelism on table is 32. But insert into DOP table as select from table takes only 8 sessions

Tags: oracle, database-performance

Degree of parallelism on oracle table is 32. But insert into DOP table as select from table takes only 8 sessions. Why insert is not happening in 32 sessions. When i check the explain plan for insert query it shows DOP is 32.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm):

> However, the optimizer limits the actual DOP to ensure parallel server
>   processes do not overwhelm the system. This limit is set by the
>   parameter PARALLEL_DEGREE_LIMIT. The default for value for this
>   parameter is CPU, which means the number of processes is limited by
>   the number of CPUs on the system (PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU * CPU_COUNT
>   * number of instances available) also known as the default DOP. By adjusting this parameter setting, you can control the maximum DOP the
>   optimizer can choose for a SQL statement.

Comment: My values are below PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU = 2, CPU_COUNT = 16, number of instances available = 1. Hence DOP is 32. When i see the explain plan for insert it shows DOP is 32. But it is inserting in 8 sessions. If possible can you please elaborate a bit.